# Is it ok to return a call to itself inside a method that has a return type?

Tags: c#

Hello all I am making a little blackjack game in Unity. Although these classes don't actually use Monobehaviour or anything just yet.

I have this method and I'm not sure it will work like this or not. I need a way for it to return the card, but if the card has already been dealt out it needs to just repeat until it finds a card that isn't already dealt to return to the original place where i invoke this method from.

```
    public Card TakeRandomCardFromDeck()
{
    var rand = new Random();
    int randomIndex = rand.Next(cards.Length);
    Card card = cards[randomIndex];
    if (card.stillInDeck)
    {
        cards[randomIndex].stillInDeck = false;
        return card;
    }
    else
    {
        return TakeRandomCardFromDeck();
    }
}
```

Im specifically worried about the else{ ....... part.

NOTE: I have already done this and whilst it seems to work, its hard to tell whether its actually ran into a card that is already dealt yet since I only have a few cards dealt so far. (I've ran it dozens of times and not had any errors in the one test deal it performs on each run)

Comment: This is just recursion, a standard programming technique since the paleolithic era. So long as it eventually starts dropping out before the stack overflows it's absolutely fine.

Comment: so it won't cause some infinite loop or fail  to return a Card to where it was called from ? excellent :]

Comment: Ps. lol some pretty advanced Cavemen doing this recursion lol :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is OK (when done with care).

The technique of using code that calls itself is called "recursion," and a method that does this is called a "recursive" method.

Many of the early definitions of what we now think of as programs and even computation itself were based on recursion, and it's essential to algorithm design paradigms like divide & conquer (see classics like QuickSort).

The trick is that this inner call is itself a function call — so it involves adding extra data onto your program's stack to track the variables of the call-within-the-call. And another for the call-within-that-call-within-the-call, and so on... (outside of special cases like tail recursion where a suitable compiler might be able to optimize it into iteration instead)

So that means your stack grows telescopically until it hits a "base case" where your function can return a value without calling itself yet again. Then the stack telescopes back, resolving each call from the inside out until the original call finally returns.

If a base case isn't guaranteed to be reached in a "reasonable" number of iterations, this can cause what's called a "Stack Overflow": your environment runs out of allocated space to keep growing the stack, and computation will terminate with an error.

In the case you've shown, as long as we have at least one card left in the deck, we're unlikely to keep repeating *too* long... but it is technically possible.

In this case though, we can make a non-recursive method that always solves the problem in a single pass, using a Fisher-Yates shuffle (also called a Knuth shuffle):

```
Card[] deck;
int cardsLeftInDeck;

public Card Draw() {
    if(cardsLeftInDeck == 0) {
        // Here you could return the "No Card"
        // or just reshuffle the discards
        // and proceed from a fresh deck like so:
        cardsLeftInDeck = deck.Length;
    }

   // Choose a random card from the remaining deck.
   int drawnIndex = Random.Range(0, cardsLeftInDeck);
   Card drawnCard = deck[drawnIndex];

   // Swap the card to the end of the remaining deck.
   // (The high indices become our discard pile)
   cardsLeftInDeck--;
   deck[drawnIndex] = deck[cardsLeftInDeck]
   deck[cardsLeftInDeck] = drawnCard;

   return drawnCard;
}
```

This always gives you a valid random card in a single try, guaranteed.

Comment: very informative many thanks. It certainly will never reach one card in the deck in this case so I think i will continue with it as is in that case. However thanks for showing me the Fisher-Yates technique as a reference for me to come back to later.